# Add up values in hashes

Tags: ruby

```
array1 = { "d1" => 2, "d2" => 3}
array2 = { "d1" => 3, "d3" => 10}
```

i want this:
`array3 = { "d1" => 5, "d2" => 3, "d3" => 10}`

i tried this, it doesn't work.   i am getting the error: **"NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass"**

```
array3 = {}
array1.each {|key, count| array3[key] += count}
array2.each {|key, count| array3[key] += count}
```

Comment: If you're concerned with conciseness, you could change this to: `array3 = array1.merge(array2){ |_, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the error because `array1.each` tries to access `array3['d1']`, which doesn't exist yet, so it returns `nil` as the value. You just need to define `array3` a bit more specifically, using `Hash.new` to tell it to assign `0` to all keys by default.

`array3 = Hash.new(0)`
`array1.each {|key, count| array3[key] += count}`
`array2.each {|key, count| array3[key] += count}`

Be careful going forward, though: the object you pass as the default value can be modified, so if you were to write `my_hash = Hash.new(Array.new); my_hash[:some_key] << 3` then *all* keys that receive a default value will share the same object. This is one of those strange gotchas in Ruby, and you would want to use the block version of `Hash.new` in that case.

Comment: the only difference is "array3 = Hash.new 0" vs. "array3 = {}", why your version worked, mine didn't.

Comment: `{}` is the same as `Hash.new()`, but `Hash.new` can take a "default value", in this case 0, to assign as the value of any key that hasn't been given a value yet.

Comment: that make sense, thanks. if i want to initialize an element in array3 to a certain value, the rest to 0, can i do that in one line instead of 2?   `array3 = Hash.new 0   array3["d5"] = 12`

Comment: No, `Hash.new(0)` will only set the *default* value. You could do `array3 = Hash.new(0); array3['d5'] = 12` on one line in the editor if you want to keep it all together, but it's still two Ruby statements. Technically you could use the block version to override one key's default value, but there's no real benefit over just assigning it.

Answer (score 4):

it is much more simplier

```
=> h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
{"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
=> h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
{"b"=>254, "c"=>300}
=> h1.merge(h2) {|key, oldval, newval| newval + oldval}
{"a"=>100, "b"=>454, "c"=>300}
```

it was undocumented in core-1.8.7 but you can read more here:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.src/M000759.html

it works on both versions

Comment: sorry, I didn't see @echoback comment

Answer (score 1):

User you have to initialize the key for the non-existent values in the second array:

```
irb(main):007:0> array1 = {"d1" => 2, "d2" => 3}
=> {"d1"=>2, "d2"=>3}
irb(main):008:0> array2 = {"d1" => 3, "d3" => 10}
=> {"d1"=>3, "d3"=>10}
irb(main):009:0> array3 = {}
=> {}
irb(main):010:0> array1.each {|key, count| array3[key] = (array3[key] || 0) + count}
=> {"d1"=>2, "d2"=>3}
irb(main):011:0> array2.each {|key, count| array3[key] = (array3[key] || 0) + count}
=> {"d1"=>3, "d3"=>10}
irb(main):012:0> array3
=> {"d1"=>5, "d2"=>3, "d3"=>10}
irb(main):013:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the **keys** in your hash are **not** integers you can use this trick which uses the fact that string.to_i gives zero

```
hash.to_a.flatten.inject{|sum, n| sum.to_s.to_i + n.to_s.to_i }
```